# Factoring for simplification?

Tags: factoring

I need to show that

$$\dfrac{\Gamma\left(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2\right)}{\Gamma\left(\alpha_1\right)\Gamma\left(\alpha_2\right)}\left[\dfrac{\tau y^{\tau \alpha_1}\delta^{\tau \alpha_2}}{y\left(y^{\tau} + \delta^{\tau}\right)^{\alpha_1 + \alpha_2}}\right] = \dfrac{\Gamma\left(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2\right)}{\Gamma\left(\alpha_1\right)\Gamma\left(\alpha_2\right)}\left\{\dfrac{\tau \left(y/\delta\right)^{\tau \alpha_1}}{y\left[1+\left(y/\delta\right)^{\tau}\right]^{\alpha_1 + \alpha_2}}\right\}\text{.}$$
I don't see what is necessary to get the expression on the right. (I've been studying for this exam too long.) Looks like some factoring, but it looks very messy.

Comment: As a good place to start, look for common things: After cancelling some stuff, you're trying to prove that $$\frac{\delta^{\tau \alpha_2}}{(y^{\tau} + \delta^{\tau})^{\alpha_1 + \alpha_2}} = \frac{\delta^{\tau \alpha_1}}{[1 + (y/\delta)^{\tau}]^{\alpha_1 + \alpha_2}}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use that $$(y^{\tau}+\delta^{\tau})^{\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2}}=\delta^{\tau(\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2})}\left(1+\left(\frac{y}{\delta}\right)^{\tau}\right)^{\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2}}$$

and $$\frac{y^{\tau\alpha_{1}}\delta^{\tau\alpha_{2}}}{\delta^{\tau(\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2})}}=\left(\frac{y}{\delta}\right)^{\tau\alpha_{1}}.$$

Comment: This is definitely not very apparent to me. How did you derive this?

Comment: @Clarinetist Factor out $y^\tau$.

Comment: You got $\tau$ in the denominators, you mean $y$.

Comment: @GitGud - Thank you, that was confusing me at first! I'll try this right now.

Comment: @GitGud Thank you for catching that.

Comment: The first equation was obvious to me, but the second equation... I definitely wouldn't have thought to do that. Thanks!

Comment: @Clarinetist The factoring should be pulling out $\delta^{\tau}$. So it should go as follows: $(y^{\tau}+\delta^{\tau})^{\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2}}=(\delta^{\tau}(1+\frac{y^{\tau}}{\delta^{\tau}}))^{\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2}}=\delta^{\tau(\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2})}(1+(\frac{y}{\delta})^{\tau})^{\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2}}$